# Get error at com.ExecuteNonQuery() while adding data into table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I am trying to save data from web form in visual studio 2015(community edition). I am repeatedly getting error:

```
no mapping exists from object type. Error at line "com.ExecuteNonQuery()".
```

I have tried various solutions mention in this forum but none of them work for me. Please help. Thank you.

Error Message：
[image]

My code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where Username='" + un.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User already exists");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (temp == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string insertquery = "insert into [Table] (Designation, Username, Email, [Password]) values (@Designation, @Username, @Email, @Password)";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquery, conn);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", dn.SelectedItem.ToString());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", un.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", em.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pw.Text);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("Managers.aspx");
                Response.Write("Registration Successful");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("error :" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above error it seems due to object typecasting is invalid.

The major difference is the implicit conversion when using AddWithValue. If you know that your executing SQL query (stored procedure) is accepting a value of type int, nvarchar, etc, there's no reason in re-declaring it in your code.

For complex type scenarios (example would be DateTime, float), I'll probably use Add since it's more explicit but AddWithValue for more straight-forward type scenarios (Int to Int).

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (temp == 0) {
     try {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
      conn.Open();

      string insertquery = "insert into [Table] (Designation, Username, Email, [Password]) values (@Designation, @Username, @Email, @Password)";

      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquery, conn);

      com.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dn.SelectedItem.ToString();
      com.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = un.Text;
      com.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = em.Text;
      com.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pw.Text;
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      Response.Redirect("Managers.aspx");
      Response.Write("Registration Successful");
      conn.Close();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
      Response.Write("error :" + ex.ToString());
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be in this line:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", dn.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

The `AddWithValue` do a mapping to determine what datatype is the object that you are passing to the method. That is failing.

Try this:

1) `com.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dn.SelectedItem.ToString();`

2) If you want to keep using `AddWithValue` debug to see what is inside `dn.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Anyway, it is always preferable to use `Add` instead `AddWithValue` because of that typical problems as the one you are having right now. Take a look at this article: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/